# Why does Bo-Katan remove her helmet?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In second season of *The Mandalorian*, Bo-Katan and her companions immediately remove their helmets after helping the titular Mandalorian fight off some people trying to kill him. Why do they do this? I understand these Mandalorians, who were born on Mandalore, don't have a strict tradition to keep their helmets on unlike the zealots of the Watch. But why do they remove their helmets here? Is it because they're uncomfortable? Do they have a different tradition that the helmet should be removed when greeting someone? Are they trying to confirm whether he's a member of the Watch, and thus deliberately provoking him? It's a bit odd that they continue removing their helmets throughout the episode too, since it irritated the Mandalorian so much the first time.

I'm most interested in in-universe answers.

Comment: What's the point of getting a well known actress to bring your previously animated character into live action if you never show her face?

Comment: It would be nice if they would stop doing it if it could end this idiotic obsession with trying to force ways in to show their face.  Don’t audition for a masked/helmeted role if you are so obsessed with your face being seen.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *Clone Wars*, but in Legends works Mandalorians almost always take their helmets off for social occasions unless they have something to hide (or are Boba Fett).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The New Mandalorians need to know if Din can be trusted.**

Bo-Katan is the leader of the New Mandalorians. She knows that there are Mandalorians alive elsewhere and she definitely doesn't know each and every one.

But, some are her enemies and some are her friends. Din has shown in the past that "false Mandalorians" (Those who wear the armor without following "The Way") should have their armor stripped, at the very least. He has not shown that he is willing to kill for it, though he has made such threats.

Bo-Katan knows who The Watch is. Din is a child of the watch. This last bit is speculation, but:

***Taking off your helmet is how you can show other Mandalorians that you're not an extremist.***

Bo-Katan wanted to show Din she was not a zealot. She had hoped Din would do the same.